# Relation between RG flow and space of vacua

Tags: renormalization, vacuum, supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking

When studying supersymmetric QFT's, it is very common to compute the *moduli space* of the theory by solving all F-term equation (derivatives of the superpotential). More precisely, one should also quotient by the complexified gauge group.

Here are three fact that I believe to be true about moduli space and IR flow:

1. Let us consider a supersymmetric QFT, dumbed theory A. Let us now take flow towards the IR and obtain an affective theory, called theory B. The moduli spaces of theory A and theory B are not necessarily the same. More generally, **the moduli space of a theory changes with the flow**.
2. Now, on the contrary, a moduli space can be seen as the space of theories, i.e. the set of all possible vev's configurations for all the scalars. **Choosing a point in the moduli space therefore introduces a scale, and implies that we are at a certain point in the flow of the theory**. Certain regions of the moduli space can then correspond to strongly coupled or weakly coupled regimes.
3. The moduli space of a theory, i.e. its space of vacua is the most low-energy thing you can do, no fields can be excited so they all take their minimum values, i.e. their moduli. So **the moduli space could be seen as the bottom of the IR flow**.

Those three pictures are clearly in contradiction. What is the problem with this way of thinking ?

I would be very interested by references about the link between RG flow, low energy-limits, and the moduli space.